# How to connect dots into groups

Tags: python, algorithm

There are n dots. n = 7. And I have information about the connected dots.

```
import numpy as np
connect = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], 
              [4, 0],[4, 4],[5, 0], [5, 5], [6, 6]])
```

for example [0, 1] means dot 0 and dot 1 are connected. How could I put dots into groups so that within groups, dots are connected. In this example, [0, 4], [0, 5] are connected, but [4, 5] is not connected, but they still belongs to the same group.
The result should look like

```
groups = [[0, 4, 5], [1], [2], [3], [6]]
```

**EDIT:**
Here is my current approach.

```
data = np.full((7, 7), 0)

for c in connect:
    data[c[0], c[1]] = 1

for c in connect:
    data[c[0], :] = data[c[0], :] + data[:, c[1]]
    data[:, c[1]] = data[c[0], :] + data[:, c[1]]

data[np.where(data != 0)] = 1
result = np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in data})
print ([np.where(row != 0)[0] for row in result])
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I updated the answer, but I think there must be something much nicer. @ScottHunter

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 similar ways that you can use to approach this problem:

1. Disjoint set (More information and implementation in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Initially treat each dot as a set of its own, for every pair of connected dots, you try combining the set if the nodes are in different sets. If you are not familiar with disjoint set, please refer to the link above, as it might get a little long.

The number of groups will be the number of sets left, and the members are described within a set.

2. Graph

Treat each dot as a node and the connection as an edge. Your goal here is to find the connected components for the graphs (the entire dots). Each connected component is a group and the members of the connected components are the member of a same group.

More on connected components (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) and you can traverse the graph using BFS or DFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).

Comment: I try to read the wiki page, but I am still confused. Do you have any example I could look at?

Comment: @JOHN not really, which part do you not understand?

Comment: I try to look at DFS, looks like the function is when you put in two vertices and the result out it will give you is the path from one node to the other. I don't think it is what I want. @Jonathan Darryl

Comment: @JOHN how to use DFS in this case: for every unvisited node, try starting DFS from that node and all nodes that are visited in the DFS is in the same group.